# Sequence and Limit Point

Tags: analysis

Let $A$ be a set and $x$ a number. Show that $x$ is a limit-point of $A$ if and only if there exists a sequence $x_1,x_2,...$ of distinct points in $A$ that converges to $x.$

For one direction, can we say that since $x$ is a limit-point, there is a neighborhood in $A$ that contains $x$ and infinitely many other points in $A,$ and just have those points as a sequence that converges to $x?$

Answer (score 2):

**Every** neighborhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $A$. Pick a point of $A$ in $(x-1,x+1)$. Then pick a different point of $A$ in $(x-\frac  1  2,x+\frac 1 2)$ and so. You can a sequence of distinct points of $A$ converging to $x$.